# Looking for just a quick 'n easy wait command

Tags: android, wait

Just after a quick wait command that will make my application stop, for say 10 milliseconds, so that it'll look like it's animating stuff (in my case a ball).

```
    public class PiranhaDrop extends Activity
    {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FrameLayout main = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    main.addView(new Drawing(this,0,0,0));
    int MyLoop=0;
    while(MyLoop<100)
    {
        main.addView(new Drawing(this,MyLoop,10,10));
        synchronized(this){wait(10);}
        //try{Thread.sleep(WaitTime);} catch (InterruptedException e){}
        MyLoop=MyLoop+1;
        main.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
            {
                float x = e.getX();
                float y = e.getY();
                FrameLayout flView = (FrameLayout) v;
                flView.addView(new Drawing(getParent(),x,y,25));
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

As you can see, just after the loop begins I've tried a few things (the WaitTime refers to a long that I got rid of, it didn't work) - neither of which have worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to wait is this:

```
try
{
    Thread.sleep(10);
}
catch (Exception e){}
```

However, note that this will run on the UI thread.
For 10ms there is no real problem and it's the preferred way to wait... But for longer periods it will result in an ugly dialog to your users saying your application is not responding.

Comment: As you said - it's a bad practice to call sleep() in UI thread. So don't present it as a solution.

Comment: I don't agree. For 10ms it's a good way... Although I don't know what a 10ms sleep would achieve

Comment: Think I've got it working using IncrediApp's code above. The emulator in Eclipse doesn't like it much but I'll see if I can get it working properly.

Comment: Note that Peter's comment below is what you should use. I only answered your original question regarding how to wait. You have some problems in your code, mainly creating tons of objects and making the garbage collector work really hard...

Answer (score 4):

No need to do this by hand. Use [frame animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html#frame-animation) (with series of bitmaps) or better a [tween animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html#tween-animation) (moving/resizing an existing view).